# Feature request: New vote close option for off topic

Tags: feature-request, on-off-topic, close-reasons

When we vote to close, we currently have a variety of options, however currently we have to select the 'other' and add a text description for questions that are not about bicycles/cycling.

I propose we have a new custom close option added under 'A community-specific reason' as follows:
"This question is not related to cycling or cycling equipment".

Had this option been available I would have been able to use it many times already for motorbike related questions

Comment: Weird. I'm pretty sure this used to be an option.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - this is possible.  Example with screenshots:

https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/questions/3701

I've added two entries but they need approval before going live:

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/site-specific-close-reasons

Comment: Not sure if you know or not, but only mods can follow those links

Comment: @AndyP I did not = thank you.   I've escalated this to mods.